# class with unknown struct as member

Tags: c++, class, struct

Is it possible to assign an unknown struct to a class in c++? Something like a virtual function maybe? Or assigning a pointer to a struct? The struct would be assigned at construction and then never change.

```
class Class{
  void someFunction(){
    //do something with the struct
  };
  struct unknownStruct;
};

struct Struct1{
    int value1;
} struct1;

struct Struct2{
    int value2;
    int value3;
} struct2;

int main()
{
    Class object1;
    Class object2;
    object1.struct=struct1;
    object2.struct=struct2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you create put a pointer to `base class` in place of your 'unknownStruct', and then later assign in every object's `unknownStruct` to whatever object of any derived class you want?

Other option is to put `void*` in that place and store whatever you want, but you'd have to worry about typecasting all the time.

Comment: structs are also classes btw. `struct` and `class` are just two keywords to declare a class. Only difference is default access

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a template

```
template<class StructType>
struct Class {
    void SomeFunction() { ... }
    StructType myStruct;
};
```

or a variant if the number of structs is limited

```
struct S1 { };
struct S2 { };
struct Class {
    void SomeFunction() { ... }
    std::variant<S1, S2> myStruct;
};
```

or polymorphism

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() = default; };
struct Class {
    void SomeFunction() { ... }
    std::unique_ptr<Base> myStruct;
};
```

or a simple void pointer

```
struct Class {
    void SomeFunction() { ... }
    void* myStruct; //std::shared_ptr<void> might be safer to use
    //or maybe std::any.
};
```

Comment: IMHO the idiomatic way is the `unique_ptr` one. Raw pointers are handy for C experienced programmers, but require special processing for destruction and copying (rule of 5).

Comment: I find that any of the first 3 methods are fine. I would discourage the use of the raw void pointer. Maybe `std::any` would be better.

Comment: would template create a copy of the struct? Or does it store the address to it?

Comment: @michox `StructType myStruct` copies it. `StructType* myStruct` stores the address.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The `unique_ptr` is a far better way than the raw `void` pointer indeed :)

Comment: Which one of those has the best memory footprint? I am on a microcontroller so that is important to me.

Comment: It depends on the compiler, but I would guesstimate that a raw `void` pointer would have the lowest memory footprint: I would hate to recommend a raw `void` pointer in any other case, but everything is fair game on microcontrollers.